# Mobile responsive column on contact form 7

Tags: html, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm new here.

I have a problem with a form I made, I needed it to wrap the field one below the other in the cell phone version, but they are next to each other, how do I make this happen?

[Picture of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOfN4.png)

This is the website I'm editing:

https://netcredbrasil.com.br/pre-cadastro-de-parceria/

I tried using break inside in css, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You have not included source code in your question, so I can’t provide an answer for your specific situation (unless you edit your question to improve it). But I *can* give a general answer which illustrates how I solve this problem in my own work.

A new CF7 form, by default, contains a name field and an email field. The relevant part of the default source code looks like this:

```
<label> Your name
    [text* your-name autocomplete:name] </label>

<label> Your email
    [email* your-email autocomplete:email] </label>

...
```

To make this pair of fields responsive, so that they display beside each other on wide screens and stack vertically on narrow screens, start by adding a wrapper element around them:

```
<div class="two-col-responsive">

  <label> Your name
      [text* your-name autocomplete:name] </label>

  <label> Your email
      [email* your-email autocomplete:email] </label>

</div>

...
```

Then style the wrapper as a `grid` and use media queries to vary the number of columns.

```
.two-col-responsive {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto; /* one column */
  gap: 0 5vw;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .two-col-responsive {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; /* two columns */
  }
}
```